# Why this merge sort is not working? It give the same unsorted array

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, merge

I did this code to implement merge sort, which takes the input array from the user and Sort that array using merge sort. But it will give the same output as in input.

I also copy the temp array (`temp[]`) to `array[]`.

Please check my code and give me the solution,
thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int array[], int mid, int low, int high) {
    int i, j, k, temp[100];
    
    i = low;
    k = low;
    j = mid + 1; 
    
    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (array[i] < array[j]) {
            temp[k] = array[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            temp[k] = array[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    
    while (i <= mid) {
        temp[k] = array[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    
    while (j <= high) {
        temp[k] = array[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        array[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int array[], int low, int high) {
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + mid) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, low, mid);
        mergeSort(array, mid + 1, high);
        merge(array, mid, low, high);
    }
}

void printArray(int *array, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void main() {
    int array[100], n, target, p;
   
    printf("How many number you want to insert?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
   
    // printf("Target: ");
    // scanf("%d", &target);
   
    for (p = 0; p < n; p++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[p]);
    } 
    
    printArray(array, n);
    mergeSort(array, 0, n);
    printArray(array, n);
}
```

here is the my output

OUTPUT:

```
How many number you want to insert?
4
6
4
7
5
6  4  7  5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two bugs.  The first is in `mergeSort`:

```
mid = (low + mid)/2;
```

This tries to define `mid` in terms of itself, while it's still an undefined value.  Change it to:

```
mid = (low + high)/2;
```

The second bug is in `main`, in the call to `mergeSort`:

```
mergeSort(array, 0, n);
```

This is an off-by-one error, since `mergeSort` is inclusive of the lower and upper bounds.  Change it to:

```
mergeSort(array, 0, n-1);
```

With these two fixes the code works as intended:

```
How many number you want to insert?
4
6
4
7
5
6  4  7  5  
4  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the last warning:

```
$ gcc -Wall sort.c 
sort.c:60:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
   60 | void main() {
      |      ^~~~
sort.c: In function ‘main’:
sort.c:62:24: warning: unused variable ‘target’ [-Wunused-variable]
   62 |     int array[100], n, target, p;
      |                        ^~~~~~
sort.c: In function ‘mergeSort’:
sort.c:43:20: warning: ‘mid’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   43 |         mid = (low + mid)/2;
      |
```